# Pattern in Parsely.js not working

Tags: php, regex, parsley.js

I'm trying to create a pattern for my school id field (e.g., 12-027-091)

This is my code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSchoolID" placeholder="School ID" 
  value="'. set_value('inputSchoolID') .'" 
  data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}$" 
  minlength="10" maxlength="10" 
required/>
```

But this does exactly nothing (No validation takes place at all while the other input are validated correctly). Do I have to add data-parsley-required="true"? (Which I did but that didn't help). I tested the regex with https://www.debuggex.com/ so It shouldn't be a typo. What do I miss?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="^[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}$"
```

seems to work instead of

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}$"
```

i don't even know why but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either

```
             pattern="[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}"
data-parsley-pattern="[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}"
```

In the last version, these will be anchored, so `$` and `^` are not useful.

Alternatively use the full regex form:

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^[0-9]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3}$/"
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/pull/861)